# Conditional column whose cells depends on each others Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame,

```
  Colonne 1   Dimension 1
0  MTN_LI2      Indicator
1  MTN_IRU      Indicator
2  MTN_ACE      Indicator
3  MTN_IME      Indicator
4     RIPP7  Organisation
5    CA_SOT     Indicator
6    CA_OTI     Indicator
7     CNW00  Organisation
8     BSNTF  Organisation
9     RIPNJ  Organisation
```

I am trying to create a Column in Pandas based on the following if condition:

If `Dimension 1 == 'Organisation'` the cell gets the value of the column `Colonne 1` cell
Else the cell gets the value of the upper cell,

Regardless of the initialization issue, can you help me find a fast way in Pandas ?

I have tried to build a column similar to 'Colonne 1' but one-cell-shifted-down and use it in the conditional column but it doesn't work because it doesn't consider the case where many successive cells are different from organisation

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Colonne 1'].where(df['Dimension 1'].eq('Organisation')).bfill()

print (df)
  Colonne 1   Dimension 1    new
0  MTN_LI2      Indicator  RIPP7
1  MTN_IRU      Indicator  RIPP7
2  MTN_ACE      Indicator  RIPP7
3  MTN_IME      Indicator  RIPP7
4     RIPP7  Organisation  RIPP7
5    CA_SOT     Indicator  CNW00
6    CA_OTI     Indicator  CNW00
7     CNW00  Organisation  CNW00
8     BSNTF  Organisation  BSNTF
9     RIPNJ  Organisation  RIPNJ
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df['Colonne 1'].where(df['Dimension 1'].eq('Organisation')).ffill()

print (df)
  Colonne 1   Dimension 1    new
0  MTN_LI2      Indicator    NaN
1  MTN_IRU      Indicator    NaN
2  MTN_ACE      Indicator    NaN
3  MTN_IME      Indicator    NaN
4     RIPP7  Organisation  RIPP7
5    CA_SOT     Indicator  RIPP7
6    CA_OTI     Indicator  RIPP7
7     CNW00  Organisation  CNW00
8     BSNTF  Organisation  BSNTF
9     RIPNJ  Organisation  RIPNJ
```

Comment: The second option is the best for my case, 
Thank you very much